# XPath Sum over sub structure

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

How do I write an XPath sum over the following structure ?

```
<Order>
     <Details>
        <Detail>
            <Quantity>10</Quantity>
            <ItemPrice>20</Quantity>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
            <Quantity>10</Quantity>
            <ItemPrice>20</Quantity>
        </Detail>
     </Details>
 </Order>
```

I want to get the sum of (quantity * itemprice)

I can do this:

```
select *
from mytable
where documentdata.exist('/Order[sum(/Details/Detail/Quantity) > 20]) = 1
```

But I want to use Quantity * ItemPrice but I cant figure out the syntax for it..

Comment: If you're using xpath 1.0, I suspect you're out of luck, going by the info in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436998/multiply-2-numbers-and-then-sum-with-xslt) (which is about xslt rather than plain xpath, so isn't an exact duplicate).

Comment: I'm using XML columns in Sql Server 2008.. and I'm querying those using mytable.exists( xpath ) = 1....  no idea what version of XPath sql server uses

Comment: I'm fairly sure there is no Microsoft product that supports xpath 2.0, unfortunately.

Comment: So sum can not operate over multiple tags? as in the above example?

Comment: @AakashM: SQL-Server implements a not full standard complain XQuery/XPath 2.0 engine.

Comment: @Roger Alsing: Check my answer for a solution without iteration.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the simplest and shortest XPath 2.0 expression to use. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
select *
from mytable
where documentdata.exist('/Order[sum(for $d in Details/Detail return $d/Quantity * $d/ItemPrice) > 20]) = 1
```

That is the right XQuery syntax so it might work with MS SQL Server as it has some limited XQuery support.

Comment: I've now implemented this in my Linq to SqlXml framework: http://rogeralsing.com/2011/02/28/linq-to-sqlxml/

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this XPath 2.0 expression:

```
/Order[sum(Details/Detail/(Quantity * ItemPrice)) gt 20]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
/*/*/sum(Detail/(Quantity * ItemPrice))
```

**when this XPath 2.0 (and also XQuery) expression is evaluated** against the provided XML document, the wanted, correct result is produced:

```
400
```

So, the complete SQL query might look like this:

```
select * from mytable
  where documentdata.exist
    ('/*[sum(*/Detail/(Quantity * ItemPrice)) > 20]' ) = 1
```