# xslt 1 and sum function

Tags: php, xml, xslt, sum, xslt-2.0

I create an invoice management system using xml and PHP but the latest PHP version does not support XSLT 2.0 - therefore I have to look for an sum() alternative. How can I transform the valid xslt 2 function "sum(unitprice * quantity)" to xslt 1.0 ?

The XML stuff is based on [John's Examples](http://www.objectech.com/exblog/xsl_2.0_invoice.html)

I tried it with a node-set, but it is not supported "xmlXPathCompOpEval: function node-set not found in"

Comment: Good question, +1. There are different possible solutions, most easy with XPath 2.0 (a single XPath expression) and more involved in XSLT 1.0 (a hand-written recursive template or using convenient templates/functions of the FXSL library).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, `sum(price*quantity)` isn't valid XSLT 2.0 syntax. I guess you mean something like `sum(for $x in * return $x/price*$x/quantity).

Summing over a computed value in XSLT 1.0 can be done in the following ways:

- two pass solution, create a node-set in which the nodes hold the computed values, then sum over the node-set
- recursive solution: write a recursive template that passes the total so far as a parameter, adds sum*quantity for the current node, then recurses to process the remaining nodes
- higher-order solution: use Dimitre Novatchev's FXSL library
- extension solution: use extension functions like saxon:sum()

Comment: Great answer! Thanks a lot!! I used the second solution (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436998/multiply-2-numbers-and-then-sum-with-xslt)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a template sumNumbers that adds the two quantities. Addition can be performed in a select statement:

```
<xsl:template name="sumNumbers">
    <xsl:param name="num1"/>
    <xsl:param name="num2"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="$num1 + $num2" />
</xsl:template>
```

should work

Comment: Umm... yeah: and then there's that!

Comment: And how would this operate on nodesets?

Answer (score 1):

**In XSLT 1.0 you can use the [FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net)'s `map()` function/template (and either FXSL's `sum()` function or the standard XPath `sum()`) function**, as shown in the following example:

**Having this XML document**:

```
<sales>
  <sale>
    <price>3.5</price>
    <quantity>2</quantity>
    <Discount>0.75</Discount>
    <Discount>0.80</Discount>
    <Discount>0.90</Discount>
  </sale>
  <sale>
    <price>3.5</price>
    <quantity>2</quantity>
    <Discount>0.75</Discount>
    <Discount>0.80</Discount>
    <Discount>0.90</Discount>
  </sale>
</sales>
```

we want to get the sum from all the sales -- this is the sum of the products: `price* quantity * discount1 * discount2 ...* discountN` for each sale.

**This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
xmlns:test-map-product="test-map-product"
exclude-result-prefixes="xsl f ext test-map-product"
>
   <xsl:import href="sum.xsl"/>
   <xsl:import href="map.xsl"/>
   <xsl:import href="product.xsl"/>

   <!-- This transformation is to be applied on:
        salesMap.xml

        It contains the code of the "sum of products" from the 
        article "The Functional Programming Language XSLT"
     -->

   <test-map-product:test-map-product/>

   <xsl:output method="text"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
     <!-- Get: map product /sales/sale -->
     <xsl:variable name="vSalesTotals">
         <xsl:variable name="vTestMap" select="document('')/*/test-map-product:*[1]"/>
         <xsl:call-template name="map">
           <xsl:with-param name="pFun" select="$vTestMap"/>
           <xsl:with-param name="pList1" select="/sales/sale"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:variable>

     <!-- Get sum map product /sales/sale -->
      <xsl:call-template name="sum">
        <xsl:with-param name="pList" select="ext:node-set($vSalesTotals)/*"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="makeproduct" mode="f:FXSL"
      match="test-map-product:*">
      <xsl:param name="arg1"/>

      <xsl:call-template name="product">
        <xsl:with-param name="pList" select="$arg1/*"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the above XML document, produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
7.5600000000000005
```

**II. XPath 2.0 solution**:

A simplified problem (the originally posted one) can be solved using a simple XPath 2.0 one-liner. If we have this XML document:

```
<sales>
  <sale>
    <price>3.5</price>
    <quantity>2</quantity>
  </sale>
  <sale>
    <price>3.5</price>
    <quantity>2</quantity>
  </sale>
</sales>
```

**then this XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
sum(/*/sale/(price*quantity))
```

**when evaluated, produces the wanted sum**:

```
14
```

**Here is an XSLT 2.0 - based verification of this fact:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:sequence select="sum(sale/(price*quantity))"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is performed on the XML document above, the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
14
```