# XSLT, sum all negative nodes and all nodes as absolute value

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I can use SUM(xpath) to sum all node values, but I also have a requirement to sum all positive node values, all negative node values and all node values treating them as absolute values. Is this possible with XSLT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sum all the positive node values, you can do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(//*[. &gt; 0])" />
```

To sum all the negative node values, you can do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(//*[. &lt; 0])" />
```

To sum the absolute values of the numbers, you can do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(//*[. &gt; 0]) - sum(//*[. &lt; 0])" />
```

Comment: Wrong. sum(-//x) gives a type error in XSLT 2.0 because unary minus can only be applied to a singleton; in XSLT 1.0 it ignores all but the first node in the node-set, which destroys the purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, it worked in the online tester I used but the negative number could have been the first node in the set, I don't remember. Applying unary minus to the value returned by `sum()` should fix this. XSLT 2.0 also has an `abs()` function that can be used instead of my last code snippet.

Comment: FWIW, switching the operands and using binary instead of unary minus is even more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Please see

[xslt 1 and sum function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447857/xslt-1-and-sum-function/7448567#7448567)

for a list of general approaches to the problem