# Using sum with substring-before XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML with several accounts and I'm trying to make the sum of several scores with the format score/max_score.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="accounts.xsl"?>

<accounts>
    <account active="yes">
        <id>1</id>
        <name>James</name>
        <score>50/100</score>
    </account>
    <account active="yes">
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Caty</name>
        <score>10/100</score>
    </account>
    <account active="yes">
        <id>3</id>
        <name>Acacia</name>
        <score>30/100</score>
    </account>
    <account active="yes">
        <id>4</id>
        <name>James</name>
        <score>50/100</score>
    </account>
    <account active="yes">
        <id>5</id>
        <name>Scoot_5</name>
        <score>40/100</score>
    </account>
</accounts>
```

And XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>

                <p>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(//accounts/account/score/number(substring-before(.,'/')))"/>  
                </p>

            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However when I run the xml says it has error and does not return the sum. Why?

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your **XSLT 2.0 transformation won't work in web browsers, which only  natively support XSLT 1.0**.

For ways of summing over elements in XSLT 1.0, see Michael Kay's answer to [XSLT 1 and sum function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7447857/290085) for general ideas.  See Dimitre Novatchev's answer to [Multiply 2 numbers and then sum with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436998/multiply-2-numbers-and-then-sum-with-xslt) for some code samples.  For actual support of XSLT 2.0 in web browsers, see [Saxon-CE](http://www.saxonica.com/ce/index.xml).

I like the recursive approach.  Here's how it applies to your problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <p>
          <xsl:call-template name="sumScores">
            <xsl:with-param name="pList" select="/accounts/account/score"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </p>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="sumScores">
    <xsl:param name="pList"/>
    <xsl:param name="pAccum" select="0"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$pList">
        <xsl:variable name="vHead" select="$pList[1]"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="sumScores">
          <xsl:with-param name="pList" select="$pList[position() > 1]"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pAccum"
                          select="$pAccum + number(substring-before($vHead,'/'))"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pAccum"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(Credit: Derived from [similar code written by Dimitre Novatchev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/437643/290085).)

**When this XSLT 1.0 transform is run with your input XML we get the desired HTML output:**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <p>180</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: With safari and firefox doesn't work. Using XPATH in Oxygen Editor it works so I don't know why in this browsers don't work! I need them to work in this browsers.

Comment: Tells me that the expression to be evaluated is invalid.

Comment: Browsers do generally not support XSLT 2.0, and chances are they never will. Run your template on the server. XSLT is not for the client side.

Comment: I'm confused because if I have a tag number instead of score (example: <number>5</number>) and do "<xsl:value-of select="sum(//accounts/account/number)"/>" it works .. why this would not work?

Comment: @SteveAwsd that's because your simplified case, without the `number()` function after the final `/`, is ok in XPath 1.0.  You need XPath 2.0 to support a function after the final `/`.

Comment: @MichaelKay First comment on this answer.

Comment: @MichaelKay, I transformed his XSLT into the esp namespace, and the answer was clear.  ...or, my initial "works here" answer elicited a not-in-Safari/Firefox comment.  One of those two.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that @kjhughes somehow worked out that you were using an XSLT 1.0 processor and that you were running in a web browser.

You need an XSLT 2.0 processor to run this. If you are indeed running in a web browser, consider Saxon-CE, which is currently the only 2.0 processor to run client-side.