# sum of the cost xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to print sum of the cost of this all entree. So what mathematically:

```
<commande date="2012-12-05" numero="c1001">
    <entree ref="p1012732NC" prix="39.98" quantite="2" />
    <entree ref="p2203633" prix="149" quantite="1" />
    <entree ref="p2103625E" prix="249" quantite="1" />
    <entree ref="p3317" prix="325" quantite="2" />
</commande>
```

sum(quantite*prix)

How can I do that with xsl? I've tried using variables with for-each loop inside and normal valye-of. but I'm still getting some strange results (I won't add this code since it's just bad).

Comment: XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?  It's much much easier in 2.0.

Comment: I use xslt version 2.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiply 2 numbers and then sum with XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436998/multiply-2-numbers-and-then-sum-with-xslt)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the current context node is the `commande` element, in XSLT 2.0 it should be as simple as

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(entree/(xs:double(@quantite) * xs:double(@prix)))" />
```

(you probably don't even need the `xs:double` conversions)