# XSL: How to sum total?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xls

I have the following XML source structure:

```
<Bills>
    <bill ID ="02">
        <Product IDP="MH001" amount="10" price="20"/>
        <Product IDP="MH002" amount="20" price="20"/>
        <Product IDP="MH003" amount="30" price="20"/>
        <Product IDP="MH004" amount="50" price="20"/>
        <Product IDP="MH005" amount="60" price="20"/>
    </bill>
    <bill ID ="01">
        <Product IDP="MH101" amount="10" price="20"/>
        <Product IDP="MH102" amount="10" price="20"/>
        <Product IDP="MH103" amount="20" price="20"/>
        <Product IDP="MH104" amount="20" price="20"/>
        <Product IDP="MH105" amount="10" price="20"/>
    </bill>
</Bills>
```

**HTMX view**
[image]
How to calculate the total?
Please help. Many thanks

Comment: Please, post the XSLT that you have so far...

Comment: need to use parse data then convert that in to int

Answer (score 0):

You might find my answer here helpful, since it is essentially the same question:

[Sum of Multiplied Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27950703/sum-of-multiplied-values/27954742#27954742)