# How to product and sum the values of two different nodes of a different complex element using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

My XML is

`<root>
    <source>
        <item>
            <id>111</id>
            <qty>2</qty>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>222</id>
            <qty>1</qty>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>333</id>
            <qty>4</qty>
        </item>
    </source>
    <target>
        <record>
            <id>111</id>
            <price>1000</price>
        </record>
        <record>
            <id>333</id>
            <price>500</price>
        </record>
    </target>
</root>`

Now i need to match the id element of source/item and target/record if it matches i need to product the

> source/item/qty * target/record/price

Once the product is done for all the matching case i should sum all product value and should get the result as

> 4000 i.e (sum(qty * price) of all matching elements.)

How to achieve this kindly help me on this , thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436998/multiply-2-numbers-and-then-sum) from Dimitre Novatchev to suit your requirement. The code is as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="target" match="record" use="id" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="sumProducts">
            <!-- get only sources with respective equivalent targets -->
            <xsl:with-param name="pList" select="*/*/item[key('target', id)]"/>
            <!-- a list of target records -->
            <xsl:with-param name="pList2" select="*/*/record"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="sumProducts">
        <xsl:param name="pList"/>
        <xsl:param name="pList2"/>
        <xsl:param name="pAccum" select="0"/>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$pList">
                <xsl:variable name="vHead" select="$pList[1]"/>
                <xsl:variable name="vHead2" select="$pList2"/>

                <xsl:call-template name="sumProducts">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pList" select="$pList[position() > 1]"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="pList2" select="$pList2"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="pAccum"
                        select="$pAccum + $vHead/qty * $vHead2[id = $vHead/id]/price"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$pAccum"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: & Dimitre thank you so much for your answer it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0, you can do:

```
<xsl:key name="target" match="record" use="id" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(source/item[key('target', id)]/(qty * key('target', id)/price))"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, We are using xslt 1.0 sinc our framework support that only.

Comment: Then why did you tag your question as XSLT 2.0?

Comment: I thought people who knows 2.0 can also help me in solving this issue.

Comment: [A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) It is not meant to describe people that you think can help you. Thank you for wasting my time.