# arithmetic expressions in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to multiply each of two nodes and find total sum, like `quantity * perUnit` and find total of all Products.
How could it be done?

```
  <Products>
    <Product>
      <name>TestProduct</name>
      <quantity>3</quantity>
      <perUnit>14.88</perUnit>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <name>Another Product</name>
      <quantity>1</quantity>
      <perUnit>2.45</perUnit>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <name>One more product</name>
      <quantity>2</quantity>
      <perUnit>4.71</perUnit>
    </Product>
  </Products>
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="TotalPrice">
    <xsl:for-each select="./Products/Product">
        <xsl:value-of select="quantity * perUnit"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

And then

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum($TotalPrice)"/>
```

Also tried this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(//quantity * //perUnit)"/>
```

But got an error:

```
Can not convert #NUMBER to a NodeList!
```

Comment: You can find the solution here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436998/multiply-2-numbers-and-then-sum

Comment: @Yauza thanks, it works!